# How to navigate long commands faster?

Tags: bash, command-line

Is there a way speed up Linux CLI  navigation when I must enter long commands?
I simply use arrows right now, and  - if I have a long command it takes some time to get from start of the command to the middle of it.

Is there a way to for example jump to the middle of the command without using arrows?

Answer (score 205, accepted):

Some useful line editing key bindings provided by the [Readline](https://readline.kablamo.org/emacs.html) library:

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>A</kbd>: go to the beginning of line
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>E</kbd>: go to the end of line
- <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>B</kbd>: skip one word backward
- <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F</kbd>: skip one word forward
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>U</kbd>: delete to the beginning of line
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>K</kbd>: delete to the end of line
- <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>D</kbd>: delete to the end of word

Comment: +1 because this works even when, for some reasons, ctrl-arrows do not work. Worth to note, for `screen` users, Ctrl-A becomes Ctrl-A A.

Comment: To undo a deletion (or move text by deleting it), use Ctrl + Y.

Comment: Ctrl+Right arrow, Ctrl+Left arrow worth mentioning.

Comment: On Ubuntu using Gnome and GnomeTerminal `Alt-A` opens the menu instead of moving the cursor.  How do you use `Alt-A` with Gnome?  I mean, Gnome is the default, so it's likely anyone reading this would be running a terminal in Gnome.

Comment: If you're connecting to Ubuntu *from* OS X over SSH you may have to use "Esc" instead of Ctrl e.g., Esc-A, Esc-E and so on. This is true for iTerm and Terminal.

Comment: I curious why Readline library doesn't provide jump to the middle, i.e. calculate the length of line, divide by two, and move cursor to this index. Is there any reason Readline library don't/can't provide this kind of handy functionality ?

Comment: Vi or Emacs mode is more efficient way to navigate. There is an answer by Evan Teitelman.

Comment: Some extra context, readline is the library that is used in Linux to read out commands. It uses  emacs mode by default which means the same key combinations are available as in the emacs editor. It's possible to switch readline to vi mode.

Comment: Mac OS X actually supports some readline shortcuts _throughout the interface_ -- even in text fields!

Comment: How do I reassign this legendary `Ctrl + Y ` to `Ctrl + Z`

Comment: Straightforward information without chitchat. Thanks!

Comment: On ubuntu 14.04 gnome terminal, `Alt + left arrow` and `Alt + right arrow` allows you to move one word forward and backward. `Alt + B` works, but `Alt + F` opens the menu.

Answer (score 87):

Some more shortcuts from [here](http://www.skorks.com/2009/09/bash-shortcuts-for-maximum-productivity/)

```
Ctrl + a  – Go to the start of the command line
Ctrl + e  – Go to the end of the command line
Ctrl + k  – Delete from cursor to the end of the command line
Ctrl + u  – Delete from cursor to the start of the command line
Ctrl + w  – Delete from cursor to start of word (i.e. delete backwards one word)
Ctrl + y  – Paste word or text that was cut using one of the deletion shortcuts (such as the one above) after the cursor
Ctrl + xx – Move between start of command line and current cursor position (and back again)
Alt  + b  – Move backward one word (or go to start of word the cursor is currently on)
Alt  + f  – Move forward one word (or go to end of word the cursor is currently on)
Alt  + d  – Delete to end of word starting at cursor (whole word if cursor is at the beginning of word)
Alt  + c  – Capitalize to end of word starting at cursor (whole word if cursor is at the beginning of word)
Alt  + u  – Make uppercase from cursor to end of word
Alt  + l  – Make lowercase from cursor to end of word
Alt  + t  – Swap current word with previous
Ctrl + f  – Move forward one character
Ctrl + b  – Move backward one character
Ctrl + d  – Delete character under the cursor
Ctrl + h  – Delete character before the cursor
Ctrl + t  – Swap character under cursor with the previous one
```

Comment: Thank you for this straightforward, chit-chat-less list.

Answer (score 17):

If you're a vi[m] and bash user, you may find it useful to make readline (used by bash) use vi-style editing by adding `set editing-mode vi` to your `~/.inputrc` or `/etc/inputrc` files. Or, you could just make bash use vi-style editing by running the bash command `set -o vi`. Add the command to your `~/.bashrc` file to make the behavior persistent.

If you're a zsh user, add `bindkey -v` to your `.zshrc` file for vi-style editting.

Comment: Great tip! To add on, please see this comment to configure your terminal to indicate the mode you're using. https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/4870/is-it-possible-to-have-vim-key-bindings-in-terminal#comment1039830_4872

Answer (score 8):

I do not know of a way to specifically jump to the middle without using the cursor keys.  However, I can recommend using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + cursor key to move from blank to blank (i.e., jump from one word to another).

Answer (score 5):

Source the code-snippet below in your .bashrc. Ctrl-a jumps to the start and pressing Ctrl-a again jumps to the middle.

```
jump_mid() {
    if [ "$READLINE_POINT" -eq "0" ]; then
        LEN=${#READLINE_LINE}
        POS=$(($LEN / 2))
        READLINE_POINT=$POS
    else
        READLINE_POINT=0
    fi
}
bind -x '"\C-a" : jump_mid'
```

Or if you want to use Ctrl-Something to directly jump to the middle, change the code to:

```
jump_mid() {
    LEN=${#READLINE_LINE}
    POS=$(($LEN / 2))
    READLINE_POINT=$POS
}
```

And bind it to something different than Ctrl-a.