# How can I go back to the first word of my command in terminal?

Tags: command-line

Sometimes I need to run some commands with long name files and If I need to change options of that command it will take a lot of time to just press left arrow.

I know that I can use `CTRL + left` to go back word by word, but is there something that it will go straight to beginning of my command?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, there is a <kbd>Home</kbd> key on your keyboard.

[image: home/end key]

Its label might vary depending on your keyboard layout and language, on german keyboards it's e.g. called <kbd>Pos 1</kbd> instead.

Another shortcut to jump to the beginning of a line is e.g. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>A</kbd>.

More shortcuts to navigate the command-line can also be found here: [How to navigate long commands faster?](https://askubuntu.com/q/45521/367990)

Answer (score 4):

<kbd>Ctrl+A</kbd> go to the beginning

<kbd>Ctrl+E</kbd> go to the end.